# How do I grant permissions to an installer (no "run as admin" mode)?

Tags: windows-8, installation, administrator, tortoise-svn, privileges

I'm trying to update my Tortoise client but when I run the file (I'm logged in as an administrator), the process fails because it can't write to *.../bin* directory.

When I right click the mouse, there's no option to run the file as an administrator. I've also tried *runas.exe* (didn't start the installation wizard) and starting *cmd* and *PowerShell* as an admin (which worked well) but failed (same error as when I simply execute the sucker).

What's up with that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Task Manager or your favorite task manager replacement.
2. Locate the `TSVNcache.exe` process and kill it.
3. You'll now be able to complete the installation regularly.

The installer will be unable to remove the `bin` folder because the `TSVNcache.exe` process still runs in it (even though the file has been deleted, the process is still in memory).

This causes the installer to be unable to remove the directory and it will falsely assume that it requires more permissions than it currently has and it will also falsely assume that it isn't running with elevated privileges (even though it probably already is).

Comment: It worked after two additional operations (not sure if both are required, though, because I got annoyed and changed both things at once). See my edit to your reply. And huge thanks!